# How to resolve class path conflict in java spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, grpc-java

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.grpc.NameResolverProvider.getScheme()Ljava/lang/String;
    at io.grpc.NameResolverRegistry.refreshProviders(NameResolverRegistry.java:96) ~[grpc-api-1.42.2.jar:3.4.7]
    at io.grpc.NameResolverRegistry.getDefaultRegistry(NameResolverRegistry.java:131) ~[grpc-api-1.42.2.jar:3.4.7]
    at net.devh.boot.grpc.client.autoconfigure.GrpcClientAutoConfiguration.grpcNameResolverRegistration(GrpcClientAutoConfiguration.java:119) ~[grpc-client-spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.13.1.RELEASE.jar:2.13.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_321]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_321]


2022-11-10 17:22:36.290 ERROR 21408 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes io.grpc.NameResolverRegistry and io.grpc.NameResolverProvider


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
io.grpc.NameResolverRegistry.refreshProviders(NameResolverRegistry.java:96)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
io.grpc.NameResolverProvider.getScheme()Ljava/lang/String;
```

The calling method's class, io.grpc.NameResolverRegistry, was loaded from the following location:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/Bashlaw/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.grpc/grpc-api/1.42.2/dd67a2446043d3903f7e0532d17b8bd2f1bfe67a/grpc-api-1.42.2.jar!/io/grpc/NameResolverRegistry.class
```

The called method's class, io.grpc.NameResolverProvider, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/Bashlaw/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.github.AfricasTalkingLtd.africastalking-java/core/3.4.8/dba39ba2047b38c53c9e645d535a1db6c1164219/core-3.4.8.jar!/io/grpc/NameResolverProvider.class
jar:file:/C:/Users/Bashlaw/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.grpc/grpc-api/1.42.2/dd67a2446043d3903f7e0532d17b8bd2f1bfe67a/grpc-api-1.42.2.jar!/io/grpc/NameResolverProvider.class
```

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

```
io.grpc.NameResolverProvider: file:/C:/Users/Bashlaw/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.github.AfricasTalkingLtd.africastalking-java/core/3.4.8/dba39ba2047b38c53c9e645d535a1db6c1164219/core-3.4.8.jar
io.grpc.NameResolver.Factory: file:/C:/Users/Bashlaw/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.github.AfricasTalkingLtd.africastalking-java/core/3.4.8/dba39ba2047b38c53c9e645d535a1db6c1164219/core-3.4.8.jar
```

I tried to exclude the path on gradle but am still getting class path conflict error.
I will appreciate your help here:

Comment: Your `com.github.AfricasTalkingLtd.africastalking-java:core:3.4.8` dependency is behaving badly - it includes classes from gRPC, from an older version (1.3.0): https://github.com/AfricasTalkingLtd/africastalking-java/blob/master/libs/server/build.gradle. Since this isn't your library, you could try downgrading your gRPC version to match this version.

Answer (score 0):

The `com.github.AfricasTalkingLtd.africastalking-java:core` dependency is built as an application. That means that it contains *all* of its dependencies - it's a so-called uber-JAR.

Since the `core` dependency contains only one class, which provides only a `main` method, try replacing it with the separate modules. These are the ones included by `core`:

```
compile project(":airtime")
compile project(":payment")
compile project(":sms")
compile project(":ussd")
compile project(":voice")
compile project(":token")
compile project(":server")
compile project(":application")
```

Includes the ones you need, and your problem should be resolved - gRPC is included from its own dependency, not from this `core` dependency. Your application can also become smaller if you omit modules you don't need.